# API to fetch ActivityParameters applied to an activity in Enterprise Architect

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I have activities on an activity diagram in Enterprise Architect for which there are some activity parameters set as shown in the figure below. Is there any way to fetch these parameters declared for an activity either through API or through EA Database.

[image]

Comment: Probably EA.Element.EmbeddedElements

Comment: Great. That worked. Any idea how to get the type of Activity Parameter (Integer, Boolean, another activity etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Enterprise Architect Java API, we can fetch the elements embedded.

```
Element activityElement = rep.GetElementByGuid(actGuid);
Collection<Element> embeddedelements = activityElement .GetEmbeddedElements();
```

Thanks to the hint in the comments section of the question.